# Как заставить service provider-a использовать кастомный класс вместо своего? Laravel 5

Tags: php, веб-программирование, laravel, classloader, extend

Итак, у нас есть сервис-провайдер, он подключает и использует внутри себя классы. Есть ли способ подменить один из его классов своим кастомным классом? Есть ли способ заставить Laravel подгрузить некоторый класс с неймспейсом сервис-провайдера, например, из своей дериктории в `app` прежде чем он будет искать его в `vendor`?

Подробнее:
В пакете `serverfireteam/panel` есть класс `Redactor` (с неймспейсом `Zofe\Rapyd\DataForm\Field`), который подключает файловый менеджер `elFinder`, который, в свою очередь, требуется заменить на другой файловый менеджер, т.к. хостер запретил использование функции proc_open() и иже с ней, которую использует `elFinder`. Мне нужно каким-то образом подсунуть ему свой кастомный класс вместо `Redactor`, не нарушая целостности пакета (т.к. редактирование vendor-ов - не по феншую)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил вопрос таким образом:
Добавил в composer.json

```
"psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/",
    "Zofe\\Rapyd\\DataForm\\Field\\": "app/Field"
}
```

где "Zofe\Rapyd\DataForm\Field\" - неймспейс класса в Redactor.php

В папку "app/Field" закинул тот самый файл Redactor.php c классом, требующим замены
Далее выполнил "composer dump-auto",
Всё, теперь класс первым делом загружается из "app/Field"